iOS Google WebRTC CMSampleBuffer in RTCVideoCapturer
I’m currently trying to integrate the following code to retrieve camera intrinsics from the CMSampleBuffer to compute the field of view (FOV):
if let captureConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video) {
    captureConnection.isEnabled = true
    captureConnection.isCameraIntrinsicMatrixDeliveryEnabled = true
}
nonisolated func computeFOV(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> Double? {
    guard let camData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, key: kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, attachmentModeOut: nil) as? Data else { return nil }
    
    let intrinsics: matrix_float3x3? = camData.withUnsafeBytes { pointer in
        if let baseAddress = pointer.baseAddress {
            return baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: matrix_float3x3.self).pointee
        }
        return nil
    }

    guard let intrinsics = intrinsics else { return nil }

    let fx = intrinsics[0][0]
    let w = 2 * intrinsics[2][0]
    return Double(atan2(w, 2 * fx))
}

However, I’m not very familiar with WebRTC on iOS, and I’m wondering where I can find the typical captureOutput with the CMSampleBuffer in the Sources -> StreamVideo package. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on where to integrate this functionality into the existing codebase.
Thanks for your help!
Best regards
